# Getting a null when returning a Generic.List in a unit test, from in-memory data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq, xunit

I've added some unit tests to an ASP.NET MVC app I've written using .NET 6. I'm using an in-memory database for the unit tests. One of the unit tests fails with the following error:

> Xunit.Sdk.IsAssignableFromException   HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Assert.IsAssignableFrom() Failure Expected:
> typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<PharmacyWarehouseV2.Models.SiteToSite>)
> Actual:   (null)   Source=xunit.assert   StackTrace:    at
> Xunit.Assert.IsAssignableFrom(Type expectedType, Object object)    at
> Xunit.Assert.IsAssignableFrom[T](Object object)    at
> PharmacyWarehouseV2.Test.SiteToSiteControllerTest.IndexTest() in
> D:\Repos\PW\PharmacyWarehouseV2\PharmacyWarehouseV2.Test\SiteToSiteControllerTest.cs:line
> 29

The strange thing is I've got another unit test I wrote in the same way, which works fine.

Here is the code for the in-memory data I'm using with Moq (note: the `SiteToSite` class is large, so I'll be removing most of the properties for brevity's sake. The only properties which are required are the first two):

```
public static IEnumerable<SiteToSite?> GetSiteToSites()
{
    // Construct some SiteToSites first
    var siteToSites = new List<SiteToSite>()
    {
        new SiteToSite()
        {
            SiteToSiteID = 1,
            DateReceived = new DateTime(2020, 7, 1),
            OrderedByName = "John Doe",
            OrderedByID = 1,
            // other properties removed for brevity
        },
        new SiteToSite()
        {
            SiteToSiteID = 2,
            DateReceived = new DateTime(2021, 3, 1),
            OrderedByName = "Teresa",
            OrderedByID = 2,
            // other properties removed for brevity
        }
    };

    // Now construct SiteToSiteItems
    var ss1 = new SiteToSiteItem()
    {
        SiteToSiteItemID = 1,
        SiteToSiteID = 1,
        ProgramName = "Program One",
        Notes = "First note"
    };
    var ss2 = new SiteToSiteItem()
    {
        SiteToSiteItemID = 2,
        SiteToSiteID = 2,
        ProgramName = "Program Two",
        Notes = "Second note"
    };
    var ss3 = new SiteToSiteItem()
    {
        SiteToSiteItemID = 3,
        SiteToSiteID = 2,
        ProgramName = "Program Two",
        Notes = "Third note"
    };

    // Now assing SiteToSiteItems to their parent SiteToSites
    siteToSites[0].SiteToSiteItems = new List<SiteToSiteItem>() { ss1 };
    siteToSites[1].SiteToSiteItems = new List<SiteToSiteItem>() { ss2, ss3 };


    return siteToSites;
}
```

I use a service/repository class. This is the method that is used in the unit test:

```cs
public IEnumerable<SiteToSite?> GetAll()
{
    var tmp = _context.SiteToSite.OrderBy(s => s.SiteToSiteID);
    return tmp;
}
```

And here's the unit test that's failing:

```cs
[Fact]
public void IndexTest()
{
    // arrange
    var mockRepo = new Mock<ISiteToSiteService>();
    mockRepo.Setup(m => m.GetAll()).Returns(SiteToSiteMockData.GetSiteToSites());
    var emptyDbContext = new PharmacyDBContext();   //won't test the AJAX calls
    var controller = new SiteToSiteController(emptyDbContext, mockRepo.Object);

    // act
    var result = controller.Index();

    // assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
    Assert.True(viewResult.ViewData.Count > 0, "viewResult does not have any records, as it should");
    var viewResultSites = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<List<SiteToSite>>(viewResult.ViewData.Model);
    if (viewResultSites.Count > 0)
    {
        // NOTE: I do not like this; it violates unit testing.
        Assert.Equal(2, viewResultSites.Count);
        Assert.Equal("John Doe", viewResultSites[0]?.OrderedByName);
    }
}
```

When I debug the test, after the `result` variable is assigned in the "act" step, it does have the data from in-memory. However, the `viewResult.ViewData.Model` is null. I don't understand how `result` has data, but `viewResult.ViewData.Model` doesn't. I've gone to the xUnit repo on GitHub to look at the documentation, but it wasn't clear to me what the problem is. What might be causing the discrepancy?

#### Addendum 1

Here's the `GetAll()` method from the SiteToSiteService:

```cs
public IEnumerable<SiteToSite?> GetAll()
{
    var tmp = _context.SiteToSite.OrderBy(s => s.SiteToSiteID);
    return tmp;
}
```

And here's the `Index()` method from the controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the related controller action?

Comment: Sure Peter, I'll add the controller action code to the original post.

Comment: @PeterCsala, thank you for asking your question. I see now I am not getting the data in the `Index` method as I thought I was. (I wrote it months ago and just forgot what was in it.) I'll work on it and get it working, then will post my solution here.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I've appended the code, which now works, on a separate unit test. The one I had been working on, I now realize I shouldn't have done, because it didn't reflect what we had in the view/controller/service.

Comment: If you have found the answer for your original question then please post it as an answer rather than amending your question. If you still have some open question then please make it explicit because after your amendments it is unclear whether you are still seeking for any advice or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posting answer on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space)*.

After Peter's question I realized I made a mistake. The `Index` action method didn't pass any data into the view. This is what was giving me a null. (For business reasons we don't show a list of site-to-sites.) So, I've put an xUnit `[Fact(Skip = "<message>")]` into the unit test for the `IndexTest`.

However, I do have a `DetailTest` unit test. Here's the code for the `DetailTest`:

```cs
[Fact]
public void DetailsTest()
{
    // arrange
    var mockRepo = new Mock<ISiteToSiteService>();
    mockRepo.Setup(m => m.Get(1)).Returns(SiteToSiteMockData.Get(1));
    var controller = new SiteToSiteController(new PharmacyDBContext(), mockRepo.Object);

    // act
    var result = controller.GetSiteToSiteById(1);

    // assert
    var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
    var viewResultSiteToSite = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<SiteToSite>(viewResult.ViewData.Model);
    Assert.Equal("John Doe", viewResultSiteToSite.OrderedByName);
}
```

Here's the action method from the controller:

```cs
public ActionResult GetSiteToSiteById(int id)
{
    var site2Site = siteToSiteService.Get(id);
    if (site2Site == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View("SiteToSiteDetail", site2Site);
}
```

and here's the `Get(int id)` method from the service/repository method:

```cs
public SiteToSite? Get(int id)
{
    var result = _context.SiteToSite.Include(i => i.SiteToSiteItems).Where(s => s.SiteToSiteID == id);
    return result.FirstOrDefault();
}
```